# Is it possible to get the AM/PM from the date picker iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi all im using a date picker and priting the time taken from picker in a label.It is working fine.and i want to print the AM/PM selected from picker.is it possible.Can anyone help me..Thanks in advance

I used the code below:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh-mm"]; 


    selected = [datePicker date];
    NSLog(@"saaa%@",selected);


    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:selected];
    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Daily Reminder: %@", dateString];

    [dateFormatter release];
    label.text=message;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, change this:
`[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh-mm"];`

to this:
`[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh-mm a"];`

Comment: here when i select for eg:3.00pm,it is displaying as"03:00pm".is there any way to cut the leading zeros here..

Comment: use this for that output [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h-mm a"];

Answer (score 2):

set dateformat like this

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh-mm a"];
```